# Synchronize PHP and MySQL Timezones

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, timezone

My timezone that I get through PHP is `UMT` by using this code:

```
$timezone = date_default_timezone_get(); // UTC
echo "The current server timezone is: " . $timezone."<br />";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');   //  2015-04-10 00:08:05
```

and MySQL gives me `pkt` as my system timezone and time `2015-04-10 05:14:38`

```
SELECT @ @system_time_zone // pkt
SELECT NOW( ) , UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW( ) ) // 2015-04-10 05:14:38
```

Due to this time difference, I am unable to fetch correct records from my database using PHP.

How can I synchronize PHP and MySQL Timezones so that both both will return the same time?

Is this possible to change timezone of MySQL using PHP?

I have tried [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/), but I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

Comment: try `utc_timestamp()` instead of `now()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql's function

```
CONVERT_TZ(timestamp_field,[mysql_timezone],[php_timezone])
```

Or change the servers timezone in php:

```
date_default_timezone_set([timezone]);
```

[php date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Or change mysql timezone:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = [timezone]
```

That statement will change the timezone for mysql, but if you restart the server it will use the default timezone.
You can set the default timezone on startup, here is the link:
[Set default timezone mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-time-zone)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

My website requires sync between mysql and PHP in a very complex way. The website provides a demo system -OR- an complete USER online office for anywhere worldwide. The server is located in US EST and I am in Australia EST. The user can be anywhere. Thus a USER LogIn could be from anywhere. With this in mind I cannot set either MySQL or PHP timezones because the USER could be located in Europe/London but the server is US/Eastern. To overcome this problem I have found that I cannot use the NOW(), CURDATE() or any other MySQL function when loading data to the MySQL tables. Thus every PHP program that I use has a header which sets the appropriate timezone PLUS variables to cater for any of the MySQL functions that I would normally have used. When loading MySQL data to the tables I then use the PHP variable instead of the MySQL function:
`$mytime = date("Y:m:d h:m:s"); // for MySQL NOW()
$myymd = date(""); // for MYSQL CURDATE()`

This is pretty tedious but does ensure that any date/time loaded to MySQL is in sync with what the program will expect the next time it is loaded by that USER from that TIMEZONE. When any PHP program/script is used by a USER for their database the timezone for that USER is always set in PHP :

`date_default_timezone_set([timezone]);`

as part of the USER LogIn process.